# Change entry in json file that matches the condition in CloudFront Update Distribution

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, jq

We have a scenario where we need to replace the TargetOriginID of CacheBehaviour in the distribution of a json file. We need to replace the Existing TargetOriginID with New Values. I have tried with below jq command but not getting any closer

```
for targetoriginID in $(jq '(.CacheBehaviors.Items[].TargetOriginId)' distconfig.json);

         do 
                  
                 
                 echo "#######fetch the new value from change behaviour json file"#######
                 NewValue=$(jq -r "map(select(.targetoriginid == ""$targetoriginID""))[].targetorigindr" changebehaviour.json)


echo "#########replace value in dist config json file with new value from change behaviour###########"
jq -r '(.CacheBehaviors.Items[].TargetOriginId | select(. == "$targetoriginID")) = "$NewValue"' distconfig.json > "tmp" && mv "tmp" distconfig.json
```

```json
{

      "CachedMethods": {
        "Quantity": 3,
        "Items": [
          "HEAD",
          "GET",
          "OPTIONS"
        ]
      }
    },
    "SmoothStreaming": false,
    "Compress": false,
    "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
      "Quantity": 0
    },
    "FunctionAssociations": {
      "Quantity": 0
    },
    "FieldLevelEncryptionId": "",
    "ForwardedValues": {
      "QueryString": true,
      "Cookies": {
        "Forward": "none"
      },
      "Headers": {
        "Quantity": 9,
        "Items": [
          "Authorization",
          "Origin",
          "access-control-allow-credentials",
          "expires",
          "access-control-max-age",
          "access-control-allow-headers",
          "cache-control",
          "access-control-allow-methods",
          "pragma"
        ]
      },
      "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Items": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    },
    "MinTTL": 0,
    "DefaultTTL": 86400,
    "MaxTTL": 31536000
  },
  "CacheBehaviors": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": [
      {
        "PathPattern": "jkl/*",
        "TargetOriginId": "nkl/Prod",
        "TrustedSigners": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "TrustedKeyGroups": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https",
        "AllowedMethods": {
          "Quantity": 7,
          "Items": [
            "HEAD",
            "DELETE",
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "OPTIONS",
            "PUT",
            "PATCH"
          ],
          "CachedMethods": {
            "Quantity": 3,
            "Items": [
              "HEAD",
              "GET",
              "OPTIONS"
            ]
          }
        },
        "SmoothStreaming": false,
        "Compress": false,
        "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "FunctionAssociations": {
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "FieldLevelEncryptionId": "",
        "ForwardedValues": {
          "QueryString": true,
          "Cookies": {
            "Forward": "all"
          },
          "Headers": {
            "Quantity": 9,
            "Items": [
              "Authorization",
              "Origin",
              "access-control-allow-credentials",
              "access-control-max-age",
              "access-control-allow-headers",
              "cache-control",
              "access-control-allow-methods",
              "expirers",
              "pragma"
            ]
          },
          "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Items": [
              "*"
            ]
          }
        },
        "MinTTL": 0,
        "DefaultTTL": 86400,
        "MaxTTL": 31536000
      },
      {
        "PathPattern": "fgh/*",
        "TargetOriginId":"xyz/Prod",
        "TrustedSigners": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "TrustedKeyGroups": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https",
        "AllowedMethods": {
          "Quantity": 7,
          "Items": [
            "HEAD",
            "DELETE",
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "OPTIONS",
            "PUT",
            "PATCH"
          ],
          "CachedMethods": {
            "Quantity": 3,
            "Items": [
              "HEAD",
              "GET",
              "OPTIONS"
            ]
          }
        },
        "SmoothStreaming": false,
        "Compress": false,
        "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "FunctionAssociations": {
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "FieldLevelEncryptionId": "",
        "ForwardedValues": {
          "QueryString": true,
          "Cookies": {
            "Forward": "none"
          },
          "Headers": {
            "Quantity": 10,
            "Items": [
              "access-control-allow-origin",
              "authorization",
              "Origin",
              "access-control-allow-credentials",
              "access-control-max-age",
              "access-control-allow-headers",
              "cache-control",
              "access-control-allow-methods",
              "expirers",
              "pragma"
            ]
          },
          "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
            "Quantity": 1,
            "Items": [
              "*"
            ]
          }
        },
        "MinTTL": 0,
        "DefaultTTL": 0,
        "MaxTTL": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

Looking for a solution to make bulk change in CacheBehaviour for all TargetOriginID's

Comment: Can you please fix the JSON, the current one is invalid.

Comment: Edited the json. "TargetOriginId" shows under 2 places. First: DefaultCacheBehavior Second: CacheBehaviors . I am specifically looking to change it under " CacheBehaviors"

Comment: @Bindu The JSON is still invalid. And while you're at it: can you remove anything that's not relevant for the question? I don't think the full 300 lines are required. Please remove the properties that are not relevant for the transformation. Looks like only the property `CacheBehavior` is required to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a second answer with some assumption. Let's start with a minimal example input:

```json
{
  "CacheBehaviors": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": [
      {
        "PathPattern": "jkl/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "nkl",
          "something else"
        ]
      },
      {
        "PathPattern": "fgh/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "xyz",
          "abc"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "IsIPV6Enabled": true
}
```

Assuming you want to define a mapping "{old1: new1, old2: new2, old3: new3, …}", the following program could work and is easily extendable:

```
(.CacheBehaviors.Items[].TargetOriginId[]) |= ({
  nkl: "wkl",
  xyz: "123",
  "something else": "is changed too",
  "not found": "never replaced"
}[.] // .)
```

And if you like to have your mapping at the top/start of your program, bind it to a variable:

```
{
  nkl: "wkl",
  xyz: "123",
  "something else": "is changed too",
  "not found": "rever replaced"
} as $mapping
| (.CacheBehaviors.Items[].TargetOriginId[]) |= ($mapping[.] // .)
```

Output after running through above's program:

```json
{
  "CacheBehaviors": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": [
      {
        "PathPattern": "jkl/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "wkl",
          "is changed too"
        ]
      },
      {
        "PathPattern": "fgh/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "123",
          "abc"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "IsIPV6Enabled": true
}
```

Is that what you are after? This chooses the new value by key from an object/dictionary/map and falls back to the current value if no mapping was found.

```
… |= ({ old: "new" }[.] // .)
```

The mapping itself could be provided as an argument to jq from a separate file:

```
jq --slurpfile mapping old_to_new_ids.json \
  '(.CacheBehaviors.Items[].TargetOriginId[]) |= ($mapping[0][.] // .)'
```

With the contents of file `old_to_new_ids.json` simply being:

```json
{
  "nkl": "wkl",
  "xyz": "123",
  "something else": "is changed too",
  "not found": "never replaced"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, the posted JSON is invalid, so it's not clear exactly what is needed, but the following is illustrative:

```
jq --arg newvalue xyz '
  (.. | objects | select(has("TargetOriginId")) | .TargetOriginId) |= $newvalue
'
```

Comment: This is changing value to xyz for all TargetOriginId's. I want to change values for 20+ TargetOriginID's at different places with a specific value

Answer (score 0):

Fixed (i.e. made valid) and reduced your JSON input down to the necessary minimum (the M in [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), that is 50 lines.

```json
{
  "CacheBehaviors": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": [
      {
        "PathPattern": "jkl/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "nkl"
        ],
        "TrustedSigners": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "TrustedKeyGroups": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https"
      },
      {
        "PathPattern": "fgh/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "xyz"
        ],
        "TrustedSigners": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "TrustedKeyGroups": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https"
      }
    ]
  },
  "CustomErrorResponses": {
    "Quantity": 0
  },
  "Comment": "vvvv",
  "Logging": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "IncludeCookies": false,
    "Bucket": "abc.s3.amazonaws.com",
    "Prefix": "std"
  },
  "WebACLId": "",
  "HttpVersion": "http2",
  "IsIPV6Enabled": true
}
```

You probably want to run a jq program similar to the following:

```
(.CacheBehaviors.Items[].TargetOriginId | select(. as $id | "nkl" | IN($id[]))) = ["wkl"]
```

It selects all `TargetOriginId`s which contain the value `"nkl"` and changes the list to only contain `"wkl"`.

Output:

```json
{
  "CacheBehaviors": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": [
      {
        "PathPattern": "jkl/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "wkl"
        ],
        "TrustedSigners": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "TrustedKeyGroups": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https"
      },
      {
        "PathPattern": "fgh/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "xyz"
        ],
        "TrustedSigners": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "TrustedKeyGroups": {
          "Enabled": false,
          "Quantity": 0
        },
        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https"
      }
    ]
  },
  "CustomErrorResponses": {
    "Quantity": 0
  },
  "Comment": "vvvv",
  "Logging": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "IncludeCookies": false,
    "Bucket": "abc.s3.amazonaws.com",
    "Prefix": "std"
  },
  "WebACLId": "",
  "HttpVersion": "http2",
  "IsIPV6Enabled": true
}
```

From the question it is unclear if `"TargetOriginId": ["nkl", "xyz"]` should become `["wkl"]` or `["wkl", "xyz"]`. Or whether `["nkl", "xyz"]` is a match because it contains different values too. Maybe you only want to select those where the full `TargetOriginId` array matches?

If you only want to match items with single-valued target origin ids, the program becomes a bit simpler:

```
(.CacheBehaviors.Items[].TargetOriginId | select(. == ["nkl"])) = ["wkl"]
```

If your target origin ids are always an array and you want to change say "[abc,nkl,xyz]" to "[abc,REPLACED,xyz]", then select only those array elements and assign them the new value.

New input (as I understood it, the Q is quite vague on this):

```json
{
  "CacheBehaviors": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": [
      {
        "PathPattern": "jkl/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "nkl",
          "something else"
        ]
      },
      {
        "PathPattern": "fgh/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "xyz",
          "abc"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "IsIPV6Enabled": true
}
```

jq:

```
(.CacheBehaviors.Items[].TargetOriginId[] | select(. == "nkl")) = "wkl"
```

Output:

```json
{
  "CacheBehaviors": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": [
      {
        "PathPattern": "jkl/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "wkl",
          "something else"
        ]
      },
      {
        "PathPattern": "fgh/*",
        "TargetOriginId": [
          "xyz",
          "abc"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "IsIPV6Enabled": true
}
```

Comment: I want to change values for 20+ TargetOriginID's with different values, not one single value

Comment: @Bindu I don't know what you mean. Can you [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74232966/edit) your question to include a valid, minimal JSON which shows what you are after exactly? As far as I am aware, this answer is a solution to your question as posted.

Comment: I have updated the script in my original description so as to what i'm trying to achieve. Let me know if it is still unclear. To keep the json short i have only mentioned 2 CacheBehaviours wherein i have close to 20 CacheBehaviour for which i need to change the 20 TargetOrginId's to a new value. I'm able to make changes to the single value but when i'm using shell script to make changes to others its not happening.

Comment: @Bindu actually, I think you made it more confusing. `TargetOriginId` was an array before, why is it a single string value now? Why do you have a shell loop? You read two different files, but only show the contents of one file. What is the difference between `TargetOriginId`, `targetoriginid`, and `targetorigindr`? Why is the sample file still hundreds of lines long, is it not possible to reduce it to a _minimal_ example? Can you show the input(s) and the expected output after performing the substitutions? You are only showing like 30% of the info required to properly answer this question.